# How can you open files which contain the word "exam" in terminal?

Tags: bash

I want to open many pdf -files which contain the word exam.
My Mac's terminal uses Bash.

The word exam is randomly in the name: sometimes at the beginner, sometimes at the midlle and sometimes at the end of the name.

**How can you open files which contain the word "Exam" in terminal?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use:

```
ls *Exam* | xargs open
```

Comment: I wouldn't use ls like that. Use find instead.

Comment: 1. Don't parse ls, ever.  2. Don't use xargs unless you are 200% certain your filenames are really simplistic (or with -0 and NULL byte separated data).  For short: Don't use ls or xargs.  Learn find(1) or open *Exam*

Comment: Don't ever parse the output of `ls` (I know I'm repeating what others have said, but I downvoted and figured out it would be nice to leave a comment). The output of `ls` is meant to be read by humans, not to be parsed!

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name "*exam*" -exec <name of pdf reader executable> {} \;
```

Comment: you might want `-iname` rather than `-name`, just in case the case varies.

Answer (score 4):

- Don't parse `ls`.  It's output is not reliable and it's only made to look at (for human parsing). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.
- Don't use `xargs`.  It mangles your data *trying* to be smarter.  Got spaces or quotes in your filenames?  You can be sure that it'll explode.

To make `xargs` behave, you'd have to go to great lengths:

```
printf '%s\0' *Exam* | xargs -0 open
```

Yes, that's rather convoluted.  Read on.

The `find` solution, while accurate, is recursive (might be what you want), but also a bit much to type in a prompt.

```
find . -name '*Exam*' -exec open {} +
```

You can make all that a lot easier by remembering that `open` on Mac OS X takes multiple arguments just fine (which is exactly what `xargs` does), so this is just fine for opening all documents in the current directory that contain the word `Exam`:

```
open *Exam*
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
acroread *Exam*.pdf
```

should work. This matches any string that has "Exam" in it, and ends with ".pdf". This also assumes that you have a command called "acroread" that knows how to read PDF:s, that may or may not be true for Mac OS X.

Comment: On Mac OS X, you can open any file with the 'open' command. For PDF files it will launch Preview.app by default.